# Question about subsets

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Im having trouble with this exercise, and couldnt find anything on it.
What is meant by that a subset $S\subset \mathbb{R^2}$ is:

a) of area zero?

b) Jordan measurable?

I think I managed to solve (b).
If we suppose that $D$ is a bounded set in the $xy$-plane, whose boundary consists of a finite number of curves, each of which is the graph of a continuous function. Then $D$ is Jordan measurable.

But regarding (a): Is it just curves that are not closed that have an area equal to $0$? For example the line $y=x$? I'm not sure about this part.

Comment: $S \subset \mathbb R^2$ is a subset of the "euclidean plane".

Comment: see [Jordan measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure).

Comment: Okay, but does this cover the part of (a) ?

Comment: Do you now a "reasonable" definition of *area* ?

Comment: Not really sure...jordan measure seems to be a different kind of calculating (length,area,volume) of more complicated shapes. But i really cant relate this in a logical way....;/

Comment: The idea is that the Line $x=1$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ that has area zero, according to the intuitive idea of area=widht x lenght.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. So curves that are not closed have an area equal to 0 basically? 
But if I for example would create a triangle consisting of 3 lines in the xy-plane, it would have an area?

Comment: Anyone who can answer my last post?

Comment: For *area*, you can see Ethan Bloch, [The real numbers and real analysis](https://books.google.it/books?id=r0qcU9U2_I4C&pg=PA297) (2011), page 297.

Comment: Page 297 does not appear, strangely for me. It claims to have maximum amount of views.

Comment: But is it true that curves that are not closed have an area equal to 0? For instance the line y=x ?